# Change a value of duplicate data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table `Employees` but here I have duplicated names and I would like to keep just one of the duplicate names (the one that has the biggest ID), and for the other ones, I need to change the `isValid` status to 0.

[image: employees table]

Comment: Can you please __post your attempted SQL__ query as [example] and the desired output too! Seems this are two questions: (1) _selecting_ the __unique `name`s__ with __max `id`__ and (2) _updating_ the __remaining/duplicate `name`s__ with __`isValid = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select e.*, max(id) over (partition by name) as max_id
      from employees
     )
update toupdate
    set isvalid = (case when id = max_id then 1 else 0 end);
```

You can also use a `where`, if you know that all the `isvalid` flags are set to `1`:

```
update toupdate
    set isvalid = 0
    where id < max_id;
```